# WPF Telerik Controls not Visible in Design Mode

Tags: wpf, telerik

I am using Telerik framework on WPF/C# project and controls are not visible in design. When I run the app, the controls (eg., RadButton) is displayed fine. Why is this happening? While default controls are working just

```
    <Window x:Class="TelerikWpfApp4.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <telerik:RadRadioButton x:Name="radRadioButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" IsChecked="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Margin="24,42,0,0"/>
    <telerik:RadListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250">
        <telerik:RadListBoxItem Content="Item 1"/>
        <telerik:RadListBoxItem Content="Item 2"/>
        <telerik:RadListBoxItem Content="Item 3"/>
    </telerik:RadListBox>
    <telerik:RadToggleButton x:Name="radToggleButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"/>
    <telerik:DataFormDateField HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="322,85,0,0"/>
    <telerik:RadSplitButton Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" IsOpen="False" IsChecked="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"/>
    <telerik:RadSplitButton Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" IsOpen="False" IsChecked="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"/>
    <telerik:RadRadioButton x:Name="radRadioButton1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" IsChecked="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="175,142,0,0"/>
    <telerik:RadButton x:Name="radButton" Content="segfsdhshdh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Margin="21,32,0,0"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before, and it had to do with the referenced assembly I was using.  Telerik has two assembly reference types xaml and noxaml, once I deleted my references and replaced them with the correct ones, I had no issues.  Here are a couple of links to the Telerik documentation about the issue:

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/common-information/troubleshooting/invisible-controls

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/xaml-vs-noxaml